# ttyUSB numbers are changing after reboot

Tags: usb, ubuntu-12.04, usbserial

I attached 4 device to ports ttyUSB0-1-2-3 they working fine also ......but when my pc boots or i restart all the ttyusb they will change,,,

e.g:

if ttyusb0--->on device 1 after boot that device 1 will start on ttyusb3/////// after pc restart's or boots ttyusb they will change all mixed up......

Please help me to solve this issue....

Can I use any dev rules..??

Comment: you need to add it to udev rules

Comment: thanks for your replay.. I am trying..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own udev rule for this.

Below code when executed will give you properties for the device so that you can use it in your custom rule.

```
udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb/dev/ttyUSB0
```

You can use the `ID_PATH` and `SUBSYSTEM`

properties for the identification.

Create a new rule file (mynewrule.rules) in

> /etc/udev/rules.d/

Amd add the specific rule like below

```
SUBSYSTEM=="yourSUBSYSTEMname", ENV{ID_PATH}=="yourIDPATH", SYMLINK+="tty-yourCustomName"
```

This udev rule creates the symlink /dev/tty-yourCustomName to the device you have connected. Its important that you use a custom name here instead of the kernel assigned node names like USB0

Comment: When I am trying to execute "udevadm info /dev/ttyUSB0" it outputs "missing option", why this happening?

Comment: try it with -a -n options

Comment: if am execute "udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb/dev/ttyUSB0", then it will shows some lines, here how can I recognize "SUBSYSTEM" and "ENV{ID_PATH}" from termina output... please help me to find it...